# jquery change event not firing in exported module

Tags: jquery, webpack

I am currently updating a project to use `webpack`. I have two scripts, a main script and a secondary script handling all shop functions. The `shop` script consists of an object with a number of functions. The object is then exported using `module.exports`.

The issue I have is that the `change` function, `productVariant.val(variant).change()`, in the `shop` script is not firing.

The event did fire when loading both scripts instead of using webpack's bundle. I'm guessing there's a simple solution to this but can't seem to solve it.

Since I have the `shop` script required in the main script, I did not include it in the `app.js`, not sure if this makes a difference.

**App.js**

```
// scripts
require('./main-js');

// css
require('../scss/style.scss');
```

**Main Script**

```
var $ = require('jquery');

var shopjs = require('./shop');
var shop = shopjs.shopObj;

// ...

$(document).ready(function () {
    // ...

    $('.variant').click(function () {
        var variant = $(this).data('variant');
        var display = $(this).data('display');
        var type = $(this).data('type');

        shop.updateVariant(variant, display, type);
    });

    // ...
});
```

**Shop Script**

```
var $ = require('jquery');

var shop = {
    updateProductQty: function (qty) {
        var productQty = $('.cart .qty');
        productQty.val(qty);
    },
    updateVariant: function (variant, display, type) {
        var productVariant = $('.cart #' + type);
        productVariant.val(variant).change();

        // ...
    }

    // ...
}

module.exports.shopObj = shop;
```

Comment: did that solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you export like that?

```
module.exports.shopObj = shop;
```

Instead do this:

```
module.exports = shop;
```

And inside **main script** import it:

```
var shopjs = require('./shop');

shopjs.updateVariant(....
```

And then use ES6 imports with babel. And don't forget NOT to use default exports, so you know what gets exported and what not.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I agree with your suggestions but they don't solve the issue. For some reason `change` function is not fired. Changing the shop file to a normal js file fires the event.